# How to set postgreSQL to use as buffers more RAM than my computer has?

Tags: postgresql, ram

I have a problem. I am learning PostgreSQL and I work with pgAdmin 4v4. At this point, I am trying to set PostgreSQL to use as buffers more RAM than my computer has. I am thinking of using something like SET shared_buffers TO '256MB' but I am not sure if it is correct. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: I want to check the difference in times of executing some queries before and after that.

Comment: Why would you ever want to do that? It would mean that the DBMS would spend all of its time waiting for the OS to move things in and out of the swap file. The difference in queries would be absolutely meaningless, because the swap  file overhead would take up all the time.

Comment: But 256MB surely is less RAM than your computer has. I don't understand.

Comment: @Laurenz Albe it was about a university assignment and the professor wanted them to test a couple of queries and how they are going to perform while pitching more RAM for PostgreSQL service. Obviously, it was written poorly by him. The same task with the same mistake was given to us 4 years later :) I answered what A.Chatz probably meant and hopefully, more of my colleagues can see it.

Answer (score 2):

`SET shared_buffers TO '256MB'`

This will not work because shared_buffers must be set at server start and cannot be changed later, and this is a command you would run after the server is already running.  You would have to put the setting in postgresql.conf, or specify it with the -B option to the "postgres" command.

You could also set it through 'alter system' command, and it would take effect at the next restart.  However, you could easily make it a setting that will cause your system to fail to start again (indeed, that appears to be your goal...), at which point you can't use 'alter system' to fix it, and will have to dig into the .conf files.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to use more RAM than your machine can physically provide. To answer part of your question as of 2024, in Windows 10/11, PostgreSQL 16.1, pgAdmin4 v.8.2 you'll have to change the `shared_buffers` size, as jjanes already mentioned correctly, and also restart the PostgreSQL server.

By default, shared_buffers are set to `128MB`:

[image]

To restart the server, in Windows 10/11, press Ctrl+Alt+Del > Task Manager > Services and then search for `postgresql` in the search bar at the top. Select the `postgresql-x64-16` service by right clicking and selecting `Restart` . That, did the job for me:
[image]

Finally, running again the `SHOW shared_buffers;` command, pgAdmin will prompt you with a Connection Warning, and by clicking 'Continue' you will be able to see the value change to 256MB.